# How to remove small noise (several irregular small shapes) from image opencv

Tags: c#, opencv

I have a series of images like:

[image]

I want to remove all those small little irregular shapes, to get only big circular shape.

I have tried denoising:

```
 Cv2.FastNlMeansDenoising(myMat, myMat,h:3);
```

But not getting nice results and process is slowed, so it appears it needs other processing, so I tried, dilate and blur:

```
            int erosionSize = 2;
            Mat element = Cv2.GetStructuringElement(MorphShapes.Cross,
                     new OpenCvSharp.Size(2 * erosionSize + 1, 2 * erosionSize + 1),
                      new OpenCvSharp.Point(erosionSize, erosionSize));
            Cv2.Dilate(myMat, myMat, element, iterations: 2);
            Cv2.Blur(myMat, myMat, new OpenCvSharp.Size(9, 9));
```

but getting something like

[image]

I guess maybe using hsv or something would help, what would be a better approach?

Comment: Have a look at [`cv2.HoughCircles()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.7/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html)

Comment: @ZdaR I once tried `HoughCircles` on a simpler task, and the performance on ellipses (even very circle-like) was really bad. My suggestion here would be some "smart" thresholding (anything more than plain binary thresholding), following [`findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) to detect the largest contour. Afterwards, [`fitEllipse`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf259efaad93098103d6c27b9e4900ffa) might help to verify the ellipseness of this contour.

Comment: You can use `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()` or `cv2.threshold()` with `OTSU`. After getting a binary image you can find contours and get the largest one.